# Running saxon xquery from Java program using net.sf.saxon.Query

Tags: java, xml, xquery, saxon

I am using Saxon 9.0.4 and included the Home Edition jar in my Eclipse project. But whenever I am issuing the query string, nothing is happening and I am not getting any output. When I am using the following command from the command line, I am getting the correct result:

```
java -cp saxon.jar net.sf.saxon.Query samplequery.xqy
```

Here is my query:

```
doc("rcmdemo5.xml")/book/chapter
```

And here is the code, I am using:

```
XQDataSource xqds = new SaxonXQDataSource();
XQConnection conn = xqds.getConnection();
XQExpression expr = conn.createExpression();
String es = "doc(\"rcm.xml\")/book/chapter";
XQResultSequence result = expr.executeQuery(es);
while (result.next()) { 
    String str  = result.getAtomicValue();
    System.out.println("Product name: " + str);
}
result.close();
expr.close();
conn.close();
```

Where am I going wrong?
Also, is it possible to get the input from a string instead of a file?

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns a sequence of zero or more element nodes (I assume from what you say that it's actually one or more). The XQJ specification states that when you call getAtomicValue(), the current item in the result sequence must be an atomic value, otherwise an exception is thrown (it doesn't atomize the result). So I would expect this to throw an exception.